# Using Vicon Datastream SDK with Unreal Engine throws error on namespace CPP in Vicons client.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdk, unreal-engine4

first of all I have to mention that I'm new to c++ but within my course of studies I have gained some experiences with programming.
Currently, I'm working on a plugin for a datastream between vicon blade 1.7 and unreal engine 4.4.3. This should be done by using the Vicon Datastream SDK v 1.4 which contains a header file, a library and a .dll file.

Right now, I'm having problems with compiling my basic plugin.
The Vicon DataStream SDK was build within an older version of visual studio than 2010. So I want to know if there is any possibility to go on working with the vicon sdk in visual studio 2013? Should I force the sdk to use the latest .dll in visual studio and if so how do I do that?

I already tried to go on working with the sdk ignoring the problem I've mentioned before.
When I built the project without changing the header file of the sdk I'm getting this error:

```
Error 2 error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
```

Here are the affected rows:

```
#ifdef WIN32

#ifdef _EXPORTING

#define CLASS_DECLSPEC    __declspec(dllexport)

#else

#define CLASS_DECLSPEC    __declspec(dllimport)

#endif // _EXPORTING


#elif defined( __GNUC__ )

#if __GNUC__ < 4

   #error gcc 4 is required.

   #endif

   #define CLASS_DECLSPEC     __attribute__((visibility("default")))

#else


#define CLASS_DECLSPEC

#endif

#include <string>

namespace ViconDataStreamSDK
{

 namespace CPP
 {
  ...
 }

}
```

If I redefine the second namespace to 'UCPP' I'm getting a huge list of errors like this one:

> Error  2      error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl
>   ViconDataStreamSDK::UCPP::Client::Client(void)"

I think it's because CPP is already defined in unreal engine but because of the dependency of the header file to the .dll file in the sdk the definition of the namespace is unchangeable in the sdk.
Is that expectation correct or am I on the wrong track?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with the name space. To fix that I did this in my UE4 Plugin header file before including the Vicon DataStreamSDK

```
#define UCPP CPP
#undef CPP
#include <Client.h> //Vicon DataStreamSDK
.....
```

At the end of this file I redifined the CPP macro

```
#define CPP PCPP
```

This compiles and works fine with no problems

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this... I was doing the same, and it worked great... in 4.13. Updating to 4.15, and this no longer works. Have you fixed this issue in a newer version of the engine?